# Retrieve max date record from two different tables

Tags: sql

**TABLE 1** - account

```
ID  account  date
-----------------------
1   SBI      01-10-2005
2   SBI      05-11-2014
3   AXIS     02-06-2003
4   AXIS     01-08-2015
```

**Table 2** - User

```
ID  account    date          user
-----------------------------------
1   SBI        01-10-2005    amit  
2   SBI        05-11-2014    rahul  
3   AXIS       02-06-2003    raghu  
4   AXIS       01-08-2015    sumit
```

From the above two tables, final output required is

```
ID  account   date          user
-----------------------------------
2   SBI       05-11-2014    rahul     
4   AXIS      01-08-2015    sumit
```

Comment: Since i'm beginner could't get through this query.

Comment: Your query is irrelevant to tables you've mentioned in question. It doesn't uses neither `account` nor `user` tables, but uses `card_account_like` table you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by grouping the values in the first table by account to pull the max date for each account.  Then once you have the max dates, you would just need to join back to the User table to get the corresponding accounts.

```
select tblUser.*
from
(
    select account, max(date) as maxDate
    from tblAccount
    where account in ('SBI','AXIS') 
    group by account
) maxDates
left join tblUser u on maxDates.account = tblUser.account
```

Comment: no problem, the query in my answer should work though.  it will pull the max dates for each account grouping, then join it to the User table to get the users associated with it

Comment: @code , thanks for your input, but what if table user does not contain "ACCOUNT" column and i want to fetch particular account giving IN clause i.e where tbluse.account in ('SBI','AXIS') while there was so many account in table......it wil be highly appreciate if you help me in this. < final output will look same as i posted in question>

Comment: if you only want accounts in ('SBI','AXIS'), then you could filter the subquery by account type (answer has been updated).  Not sure what you mean "tblUser does not contain account column", because your question has an account column for tblUser?

Comment: Assume that tblUser does not contain account column and make query base on this.(But with that output)

Comment: sort of, but then how would you join to it?  what does the table look like?